# XCode uses non-existing sqlite database

Tags: ios, xcode

I am opening an SQLite database in my project.
I dropped this database in the "Supporting Files" folder of the project.
I removed the sqlite database at some point of time and replaced it with a newer version.

I noticed that it seemed to use an older version of it.
To prove that I removed the database from the "Supporting File", renamed my sqlite file and dropped it in there again.

Theoretically Xcode should not be able to find the database anymore, but it keeps using the old database happily.

I tried all kinds of "Clean", but the problem persists.

Does anybody have any suggestions for me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The runtime copies the version of the sqlite to the simulator/physical device.

uninstall the app and run it again, it should copy the new version to the simulator/device

Comment: Thank you for your reply! And can I somehow ensure that my latest database is used? I can not ask the users to delete my app when I have updated the database.

Comment: when you say update the database, you mean structure(table, columns...) or data?

Comment: Personally, I always have a configuration table in my database that has the database version. If either (a) there is not a copy of the database in `Documents` or (b) it exists, but the version number is lower than the app is expecting, then I copy the database from the bundle to the `Documents` folder.

Comment: The answer above is correct. You can't replace the physical database file once your app is install. This is also true for core data. instead you need to provide logic to update your existing database to the new version.

Comment: I am not sure if I agree on that. My problem was something else (I forgot to check "Add to target" when I dropped my new database into the supporting files). After I improved that, it went fine, so I am not sure whether one can really not replace an existing db.